# Going session-less with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, session

I've been doing a lot of research lately and it appears to me that going stateless serverside brings benefits to both performance & scalability.

I am although trying to figure out how to achieve session-less-ness on Node.JS. It seems to me that basically all I have to do is assign a token to a logged in user, so I would have something like this in my DB:

```
{ user:'foo@example.com', pass:'123456', token:'long_id_here' }
```

so that the token can be send with every HTTP request like this:

```
/set/:key/:val/:token
```

to be checked against aforementioned DB object. Is this what it is actually meant to be a session-less web service?

If this is the right way, then I do not understand things like token expiry, and other security issues. I would like to be pointed out to NPM package of some sort?

---

On a side note, is it best for a token, to use a hash of the user+password, or to assign a different one at every login?

Comment: Unless you include sessions (like with connect (or express which includes it) you're not doing sessions in the first place. All you have to do is to send the authorization token on every request (or the user+pass hash). Once you have tokens and logins you have sessions and state, "logged in" is a user state.

Comment: the only problem is that that user+pass hash or whatever token it is, is stored for some time in the client's memory. that might lead to big security problems for that particular user.

Comment: So don't store it in the client's memory. Otherwise you have sessions. What you describe with the token is _exactly_ how sessions are usually implemented - the server generates a token (called session id) and sends it to the client, then the client sends it back on requests and the server validates it. This is state which you say you want to avoid.

Comment: oh. that's right, aha! It seems like I'm failing to understand the whole session-less-ness concept. Have any link that might help me understading?

Comment: Have you given [this entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)) a try? Check the external links too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason to go sessionless is that most default session implementations use an in-memory store. That means that the session information is stored in memory local to that instance. Most websites these days are scaling out as traffic increases. This means they add more servers and balance the load between the servers. The problem with in-memory session stores is your user can log into Server 1, but if their next request is routed to Server 2, they don't have a session created yet and will appear to be logged off.

You don't necessarily need to go sessionless to scale out with node or any other server side language. You just need to use a session that isn't in local memory that would be accessible to all nodes. If you're using something like Express or Connect, you can easily use a session implementation like [connect-redis](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis) which will enable you to have a fast session store which is accessible to all of your node instances so it doesn't matter which one is hit.